# how can i remove this error while installing bootstrap package of node?

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, json, twitter-bootstrap

npm : The term 'npm' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or
if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1

- npm i bootstrap
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (npm:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
  ```

Comment: Have you installed npm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I  request you to check the version of the node. If you do not find any please install node globally and then do npm i bootstrap

```
node --version
```